# Pandas Dataframe | Check if value is set for at least X minutes | Non-linear-timestamp-index

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, timestamp, intervals

I have problem with my dataset.

Let's presume my dataset looks like this

```
timestamp           | zone 
2022-06-01 05:00:06 | yellow
2022-06-01 05:01:07 | yellow
2022-06-01 05:02:10 | yellow
2022-06-01 05:03:05 | yellow
2022-06-01 05:07:04 | yellow
2022-06-01 05:10:05 | orange
2022-06-01 05:11:05 | orange
2022-06-01 05:12:05 | orange
2022-06-01 05:16:04 | orange
2022-06-01 05:17:04 | orange
```

`timestamp` column is the index
The yellow and orange `zones` represent a calculated zone.

Condition:
A zone change can only happen if the previous zone has been set for at least X minutes (let's presume its 15 minutes for this example)

Excepted result:

```
timestamp           | zone 
2022-06-01 05:00:06 | yellow
2022-06-01 05:01:07 | yellow
2022-06-01 05:02:10 | yellow
2022-06-01 05:03:05 | yellow
2022-06-01 05:07:04 | yellow
2022-06-01 05:10:05 | yellow
2022-06-01 05:11:05 | yellow
2022-06-01 05:12:05 | yellow
2022-06-01 05:16:04 | yellow
2022-06-01 05:17:04 | orange
```

Because the yellow zone was set from `05:00:06`. This means that for at least 15 minutes the yellow zone must be set, without taking into account the previously performed zone calculation. This means that the yellow zone must be set until `05:16:04`. From then on, the zone can be set orange.

I believe there are two ways to do this. One is to check the elapsed time while the zone is being calculated, the other is to change the zone after it has been calculated.
My priority is performance as I plan to use this data in a dashboard. The calculation of the zone is done with the `np.select` method

Just imagine there are values that are being compared to thresholds

```
conditions = [
    (df.value <= df.threshold_red), # red
    (df.value> df.threshold_red) & (df.value<= df.threshold_orange), # orange
    (df.value> df.threshold_orange) & (df.value<= df.threshold_green), # yellow
    (df.value> df.threshold_green), # green
]
zones = ["red" ,"orange", "yellow", "green"]

df["zone"] = np.select(conditions, zones)
```

How am I able to this? I have used `.apply()` with `lambda`, but I am not able to get the result...

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Ocamond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a loop:

```py
result = []
ts = pd.Timestamp(0)
assigned_zone = None

for timestamp, zone in df["zone"].items():
    if timestamp - ts > pd.Timedelta(minutes=15) and assigned_zone != zone:
        ts = timestamp
        assigned_zone = zone
    result.append(assigned_zone)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I wanted. Is it possible to vectorize this operation?